# The Expo SDK requires Expo to run. It appears the native

Tags: react-native

Complete Error is "The Expo SDK requires Expo to run. It appears the native Expo modules are unavailable and this code is not running on Expo. Visit https://docs.expo.io 153 to learn more about developing an Expo project."

I am unable to resolve this issue. I am running React Native Project on android emulator..! [image]

Comment: I'm also seeing this on a brand new `expo init --template bare-minimum` without any customization, too